# Meta tags (i.e <title>) in Meteor + Angular-Ui-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

Is there any way that meta tags could be either controlled by or included in Angular templates with Angular-Ui-Router?

In Meteor Angular your app cannot be wrapped like this: `<html ng-app="app">`, it has to be at least `<body ng-app="app">` to work - Meteor looks after all CSS and JS dependecies. Therefore your Angular app has no way to access the `<head>` (say with `$rootScope`).

Without Angular-Ui-Router you can simply add (*partyDetails.html*):

```
<head>
    <title>Details of party {{}}</title>
</head>
```

in your template, which doesn't work with Ui-Router, I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module './partyDetails.html'
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

It's OK after I remove `<head>` tag.

I need to have tags dynamic (like mentioned `<title></title>` but not only!) on my website - is it actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use [yasinuslu:blaze-meta](https://github.com/yasinuslu/blaze-meta). Your component controller:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Meta } from 'meteor/yasinuslu:blaze-meta';

//..

class PartyDetailsCtrl {
    constructor($stateParams, $scope) {
        'ngInject';

        //..

        Meta.config({
            options: {
                title: "Default Title",
                suffix: "Socially",
                separator: " — "
            }
        })

        Meta.set({
          name: 'name',
          property: 'description',
          content: 'Meta description'
        });

        Meta.setTitle("Party Details");

    }
    //..
}
//..
```

I believe `Meta.config({})` could be placed in `.run` block of your app. Hope that helps!